# Are the functions $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$ linearly independent? $a\sin^2(x)+b\cos^2(x)=0$, such that the domain is the set $~\{0\}~$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Are the functions $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$ linearly independent? $a\sin^2(x)+b\cos^2(x)=0$, such that the domain is the set $\{0\}$. (Only has the element zero).

Because if you plug the value $0$ in the equation,
it is equal to $a(0)+b1=0$ so $b$ must be zero, but  $a$  can be any value and the equation remains true, Right?

So by the definition would be linearly dependent instead.

I'm confused. Because I'm aware that those functions are linearly independent for all reals.

Comment: Sorry for my awful English.

Comment: sen(x) means what? you mean $\sin$ ?

Comment: * i mean Sin(x)

Comment: The domain is the set {0} only has one element. So you only can plug one value in the function.

Comment: I agree that it is linearly independent in other sets.

Comment: So the first question is: “What is your vector space?” If the vector space is “functions $\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}$”, then they are obviously **not** linearly independent, because $\sin^2(x)$ is the zero function, and so it is a multiple of $\cos^2(x)$. If you don’t say what your vector space is, most people will assume you mean “functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$”.

Comment: Sorry. I'm just learning the concept. That was the question.

Comment: And I’m pointing out that “linear independent” and “linear dependent” are not absolute concepts; they don’t make sense in the absence of a vector space, which you should specify either explicitly, by mutual agreement, or by convention. If you aren’t sure what the vector space would be understood to be, then you should say what it is explicitly.

Comment: Please don’t write “CLOSED” in a question that is **not** closed.

Comment: Downvotes to all the answerers who, instead of answering the actual question, answered a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using $\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x) = 1 \implies \sin^2(x) = 1 - \cos^2(x)$, you get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
a\sin^2(x) + b\cos^2(x) & = 0 \\
a(1 - \cos^2(x)) + b\cos^2(x) & = 0 \\
a - a\cos^2(x) + b\cos^2(x) & = 0 \\
a + (b - a)\cos^2(x) = 0
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are constants, but $\cos^2(x)$ varies with $x$ with $0 \le \cos^2(x) \le 1$, the equation in \eqref{eq1} can only always be true only if $b - a = 0$, so then $a = 0$ also, resulting in $b = 0$. Thus, this shows $\sin^2(x)$ and $\cos^2(x)$ are linearly independent.

Update: I misinterpreted the question's original wording. As discussed in the comments below, if the domain is just a single point, you're using $2$ functions and the concept of (in)dependence can be considered to apply, then regardless of what the domain value is and what $2$ functions you're checking, you'll always determine they are linearly dependent. This is because you have one equation in $2$ unknowns of $a$ and $b$. Thus, this system is under-determined, meaning there will always be at least one free parameter among $a$ and $b$ which can take on any value. As stated in the question, for this particular case using $x = 0$ only, $b = 0$ and $a$ can take on any value.

Comment: But if the function f(x)= Sin(x)^2 and g(x)=0(x) then f(x)=g(x) for all x∈{0}. That means that the function sin is equal to the function constant cero, in this context of course. And the function cero is linearly dependent, always.

Comment: @RodrigoSango I'm not sure if I completely understand your comment. Yes, the equation can be true for certain special values of $x$, such as $x = 0$, without both $a$ and $b$ being $0$. However, to show linear independence, the linear equation must be true for *all* values of $x$ *only* when the constants are both $0$. As the comments, my answer, and the other answer all show, both $a$ and $b$ in $a\sin^2(x) + b\cos^2(x) = 0$ must $0$ for the equation to be true for all values of $x$.

Comment: @RodrigoSango I'm sorry. I see now what the question is specifically asking, i.e., you just have the one point in the domain. I originally thought the $\{0\}$ was referring to the set of values of $a,b$. In your case, $\cos(0) = 1$ and $\sin(0) = 0$, so the equation becomes $a(0) + b(1) = 0$. In that case, you're right that $b = 0$, but $a$ can be anything. However, I'm not sure if the concept of linear independence applies, or really makes sense, when the domain is just one point. Nonetheless, if linear (in)dependence does apply in that case, then you're correct.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but i defined my function in a set with only one value.

Comment: I'm learning the concept of linear independence. Thats why I pick a very particular set.

Comment: Just to know If I'm understanding it.

Comment: Thank you John! That was the question. Thank you for your patience. I don't know  if it has sense either with only one point. Haha.

Comment: @RodrigoSango Thanks for explaining what you're trying to do. Note that if you choose a set of just one value, then regardless of what that value is and what functions you're checking, you'll *always* determine they are linearly dependent. This is because you have one equation in $2$ unknowns of $a$ and $b$. Thus, this system is over-determined, meaning there will always be at least one free parameter among $a$ and $b$ which can take on any value.

Comment: @RodrigoSango You're welcome. I'm glad you understand now. Note that in my previous comment, I should've said the system is under-determined instead of over-determined.

Answer (score 3):

Let$$a\sin^2(x)+b\cos^2(x) = 0 $$

$$x=0\implies b=0$$

and $$x=\pi/2\implies a=0$$

Thus the two functions are linearly independent.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C[-\pi,\pi]$ be the vector space of all continuous functions. Let us consider a subset of the vector space $C[-\pi,\pi]$ as $V = \{\sin^2(x),\cos^2(x)\}$. We want to analyze whether set $V$ is linearly independent?

Let us consider the linear combination set to zero, like $a \sin^2(x) + b \cos^2(x) =0$ and if that implies $a=0,b=0$, then we have the set $V$ as the linearly independent set.

We must observe that this is true for all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$.

So we put the values of $x$ (we utilize this freedom) such that we get the value of $a,b$ easily. you can put $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and obtain an equation in $a$ and $b$ and then you can also put say $x = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and then obtain another equation in $a$ and $b$. Now having two equations in two unknowns $a$ and $b$, you can solve for $a$ and $b$.

But an easy way to go is $x=0$ where $\sin(x) =0, \cos(x) = 1$ giving us $b=0$ and next considering $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$, we have $\sin(x) = 1, \cos(x)  =0$, giving us $a=0$. thus since we have $a=0,b=0$. This implies that the set $V$ is linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you very much Baymax. That was a very clear explanation